# Python Print Linked List multiple Times

Tags: python, linked-list

I was a bit surprised when I wrote a print function for a Linked List implementation in Python (created purely for studying purposes) when calling the print function a second time only gave me the second part of the list:

17 77 31
54 26 93

On further thought, of course it makes sense, since the head of the instance is modified by the print function.

I wonder if this is the usual way to print a linked list (in the context of academic exercises), and also how I can reset the head each time I call the print method? Also would I put the code to move the head back to the start of the list inside the print function?

```
    ...
    def print_list(self):
        while self.head is not None:
            print(self.head, end=" ")
            self.head = self.head.next
        print()


mylist = UnorderedList()

mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(77)
mylist.add(17)

mylist.print_list()

mylist.add(93)
mylist.add(26)
mylist.add(54)

mylist.print_list()
```

Comment: Assign `self.head` to a local variable and modify this variable instead for printing.

Comment: You don't want to modify the list when you are printing it. `self.head = self.head.next` modifies the list.

Comment: Perhaps this is better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?